# Ignore Pointer make list view non scrollable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, pull-to-refresh, flutter-inappwebview

I am making an application that is using webviews (**flutter_inappwebview: 5.7.2+3**) and need to apply refresh indicator to refresh the page. There are two cases that i want to work together. But when i fix one case other case not working. Can anyone provide me a better solution for achieving this. I am sharing the code with you.

**Case 1:** When I use ignore pointer with listview, ListView dont scroll and refresh indicator not work.

**Case 2:** If i dont use ignore pointer, then click buttons (menu Icon) behind listview not clicked.

**Note:** I just comment out the IgnorePointer widget in below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() => runApp(
    MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: WebViewWidget()));

class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewWidget> createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
  late InAppWebViewController inAppWebViewController;
  Color ACCENT_COLOR = Colors.black;
  Color SECOND_ACCENT_COLOR = Colors.orange;
  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          color: ACCENT_COLOR,
          onRefresh: () {
            print("Reload");
            return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
              inAppWebViewController.reload();
            });
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              InAppWebView(
                // pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                    url: Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/development")),
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                    useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
                    // useOnLoadResource: true,
                  ),
                ),
                onLoadStart: (con, uri) {
                  print("on Load Start ${uri.toString()}");
                },
                onLoadStop: (con, uri) {
                  print("on Load Stop ${uri.toString()}");
                },
                onUpdateVisitedHistory: (con, link, cond) {
                  print("onUpdateVisitedHistory");
                },
                shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                  final currentUrl = navigationAction.request.url.toString();
                  print("Do navigation");
                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                  inAppWebViewController = controller;
                },
                onProgressChanged:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                  // print("Progress: $_progress");
                },
              ),
              //TODO Implement refresh indicator
// IgnorePointer(
              //   child:
              ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              // ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: issue]

Comment: Give screenshot or something i tried your code and still i don't understood what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I had updated the entire code and add screenshot as well. I also highlight the area with red color which is unclickable as i had added Stack->ListView->Container with some height. Is there any way that i can click those icons and refresh indicator property both.

Comment: But why you want to add a `ListView` on top of the `webView`.

Comment: Basically i want to add a functionality of Refresh Indicator property. Refresh Indicator work only when it have a listview in Stack.

Comment: so you need the refresh Indicator to refresh the webpage right! then why you want the ignore pointer?

Comment: Case 1: When I use ignore pointer with listview, ListView dont scroll and refresh indicator not work. But Icons behind listView work perfectly due to Ignore pointer true.

Case 2: If i dont use ignore pointer, then click buttons (menu Icon) behind listview not clicked. Here Refresh indicator works. This is the current status of code.

Can You help me in this, where refresh indicator work too along with menu icons,

Comment: Yes, I need the refresh Indicator to refresh the webpage. And i am trying to achieve this thing using Ignore pointer, If there is any other way that we can achieve this. Let me know too. I will be thankful to you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing all these things when you just want to `refresh` the `webPage`, You can just use the built-in refresh controller of the `InAppWebView` with `pullToRefreshController` parameter, just add the below code in your `InAppWebView`:

```
pullToRefreshController: PullToRefreshController(
   onRefresh: () => inAppWebViewController.reload(),
),
```

See here i've just called the `PullToRefreshController` class and reloaded the webPage with `inAppWebViewController.reload()` in `onRefresh`

You also make a separate controller for it of type `PullToRefreshController` but there's no need for that.

Comment: I tried this. But it is not working on my side. Can you share the working code on your side.

Comment: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1021
I guess this is the issue